# notepad++ regular expression remove all text between curly brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

```
function get_last_word($sentance){
    $wordArr = explode(' ', $sentance);
    $last_word = trim($wordArr[count($wordArr) - 1]);
    runDebug( __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, "Sentance: $sentance. Last word:$last_word",4);
    return $last_word;
}
```

i want to remove all text between {}
result should be:

```
function get_last_word($sentance){}
```

i have tried

```
{+.*}
```

and its working only when curly brackets are on same line

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Newer version of Notepad++ supports multi-line matching (I am now using 6.1.3)

In the Find/Replace dialog, next to the "Regular Expression" radio button, there is a checkbox called ". matches newline" which means multi-line matching.

Then, use `\{.*?\}` (which is a ungreedy match) to achieve what you want.

Beware that it does not match braces for you.  For example

```
foo {
  bar {
    blabalbla
  }
  xxx {
    yyy
  }
}
```

will give you

```
foo {}
  xxx {
    yyy
  }
}
```

(I believe there are other questions in SO about brace matching in regex, you may have a look, though I wonder if they will work in notepad++)

Comment: multiline matching was the main issue, upgraded to latest version problem solved thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

You should be fine when you just replace `\{[^{}]+\}` with `{}`, repeatedly...

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thank you! @Ωmega. This expression helped me a lot. Even though I never fully understand the meaning.

Comment: @Bob - For better understanding, I have added visualization to my answer. What it says is: Replace `{`, followed by one or more of characters others then `{` or `}`, followed by `}`, with `{}`...

Comment: That makes much more sense to me. I have tried to study a little Regular Expression but never use them in such a way. The explanation is very enlightening. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
(?<=\{)[^}]+(?=\})
```

this will match anything that falls between { and }

Comment: What version are you using? I'm using np++ 6.1.4, checked it with the exact text from the original post.